# Navbar component works in normal cases but breaks incase of getstatic props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

[image: The error I am getting when navbar is in]I am trying to make a page with getstaticprops but I am unable to include my navbar component in it as console screams out element type is invalid. I can use the same navbar component during normal page rendering without static or server props. my staticprops page

```
import {Navbar} from "../components/schema/Navbar"

export default function Dope({users}) {
    console.log(users)
    return (
        <div>
            {/* <Navbar /> */}
            <main>
                <div>
                    {users.length === 0 ? (
                        <h2>No users added</h2>
                    ) : (
                        users.map((user, i) => (
                            <h1 key={i}>{user}</h1>
                        ))
                    )}
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps(ctx) {
     // get the current environment
     let dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
     let { DEV_URL, PROD_URL } = process.env;
 
     // request posts from api
     let response = await fetch(`${dev ? DEV_URL : PROD_URL}/api/users`);
     // extract the data
     let data = await response.json();

    return {
        props : {
            users : data['message']
        }
    }
}
```

my navbar component is too big to fit in here but it returns a regular navbar without any fetch operations and uses tailwindcss where as I did not make use of tailwind to style this page yet. can this be the reason? although I feel it isn't
the api endpoint works fine as well.

Edit:
my navbar is using Popover(panel, button, group), transition elements from headlessui
and Fragment from react

```
import { Fragment } from 'react'
import { Popover, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import {
  BookmarkAltIcon,
  CalendarIcon,
  ChartBarIcon,
  CursorClickIcon,
  MenuIcon,
  RefreshIcon,
  ShieldCheckIcon,
  SupportIcon,
  ViewGridIcon,
  XIcon,
} from '@heroicons/react/outline'
import { ChevronDownIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'

const features = [
  {
    name: 'Airdrops',
    href: '#',
    description: 'Get a better understanding of where your traffic is coming from.',
    icon: ChartBarIcon,
  },
  {
    name: 'Updates',
    href: '#',
    description: 'Speak directly to your customers in a more meaningful way.',
    icon: CursorClickIcon,
  },
  { name: 'Airdrop Tracer', href: '#', description: "Your customers' data will be safe and secure.", icon: ShieldCheckIcon },
  {
    name: 'FAQ',
    href: '#',
    description: "Connect with third-party tools that you're already using.",
    icon: ViewGridIcon,
  },
  {
    name: 'About',
    href: '#',
    description: 'Build strategic funnels that will drive your customers to convert',
    icon: RefreshIcon,
  },
]

const resources = [
  {
    name: 'Help Center',
    description: 'Get all of your questions answered in our forums or contact support.',
    href: '#',
    icon: SupportIcon,
  },
  {
    name: 'Guides',
    description: 'Learn how to maximize our platform to get the most out of it.',
    href: '#',
    icon: BookmarkAltIcon,
  },
  {
    name: 'Events',
    description: 'See what meet-ups and other events we might be planning near you.',
    href: '#',
    icon: CalendarIcon,
  },
  { name: 'Security', description: 'Understand how we take your privacy seriously.', href: '#', icon: ShieldCheckIcon },
]


function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div className="relative bg-gray-50">
      <Popover className="relative bg-white shadow">
        <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6">
          <div className="flex justify-between items-center py-6 md:justify-start md:space-x-10">
            <div className="flex justify-start lg:w-0 lg:flex-1">
              <a href="#">
                <span className="sr-only">Workflow</span>
                <img
                  className="h-8 w-auto sm:h-10"
                  src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-indigo-600.svg"
                  alt=""
                />
              </a>
            </div>
            <div className="-mr-2 -my-2 md:hidden">
              <Popover.Button className="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500">
                <span className="sr-only">Open menu</span>
                <MenuIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
              </Popover.Button>
            </div>
            <Popover.Group as="nav" className="hidden md:flex space-x-10">
              
              <a href="#" className="text-base font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">
                Airdrops
              </a>

              <a href="#" className="text-base font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">
                Potential Airdrops
              </a>
              <a href="#" className="text-base font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">
                Airdrop Tracer
              </a>

              <Popover className="relative">
                {({ open }) => (
                  <>
                    <Popover.Button
                      className={classNames(
                        open ? 'text-gray-900' : 'text-gray-500',
                        'group bg-white rounded-md inline-flex items-center text-base font-medium hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none'
                      )}
                    >
                      <span>More</span>
                      <ChevronDownIcon
                        className={classNames(
                          open ? 'text-gray-600' : 'text-gray-400',
                          'ml-1 mt-2 h-5 w-5 group-hover:text-gray-500'
                        )}
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      />
                    </Popover.Button>

                    <Transition
                      as={Fragment}
                      enter="transition ease-out duration-200"
                      enterFrom="opacity-0 translate-y-1"
                      enterTo="opacity-100 translate-y-0"
                      leave="transition ease-in duration-150"
                      leaveFrom="opacity-100 translate-y-0"
                      leaveTo="opacity-0 translate-y-1"
                    >
                      <Popover.Panel className="absolute left-1/2 z-10 transform -translate-x-1/2 mt-3 px-2 w-screen max-w-md sm:px-0">
                        <div className="rounded-lg shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 overflow-hidden">
                          <div className="relative grid gap-6 bg-white px-5 py-6 sm:gap-8 sm:p-8">
                            {resources.map((item) => (
                              <a
                                key={item.name}
                                href={item.href}
                                className="-m-3 p-3 flex items-start rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-50"
                              >
                                <item.icon className="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 text-indigo-600" aria-hidden="true" />
                                <div className="ml-4">
                                  <p className="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">{item.name}</p>
                                  <p className="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">{item.description}</p>
                                </div>
                              </a>
                            ))}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </Popover.Panel>
                    </Transition>
                  </>
                )}
              </Popover>
            </Popover.Group>
            <div className="hidden md:flex items-center justify-end md:flex-1 lg:w-0">
              <a href="#" className="whitespace-nowrap text-base font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">
                Sign in
              </a>
              <a
                href="#"
                className="ml-8 whitespace-nowrap inline-flex items-center justify-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-base font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700"
              >
                Sign up
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <Transition
          as={Fragment}
          enter="duration-200 ease-out"
          enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
          enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100"
          leave="duration-100 ease-in"
          leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
          leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95"
        >
          <Popover.Panel
            focus
            className="absolute top-0 inset-x-0 z-10 p-2 transition transform origin-top-right md:hidden"
          >
            <div className="rounded-lg shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 bg-white divide-y-2 divide-gray-50">
              <div className="pt-5 pb-6 px-5">
                <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      className="h-8 w-auto"
                      src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-indigo-600.svg"
                      alt="Workflow"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="-mr-2">
                    <Popover.Button className="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500">
                      <span className="sr-only">Close menu</span>
                      <XIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                    </Popover.Button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="mt-6">
                  <nav className="grid gap-y-8">
                    {features.map((item) => (
                      <a
                        key={item.name}
                        href={item.href}
                        className="-m-3 p-3 flex items-center rounded-md hover:bg-gray-50"
                      >
                        <item.icon className="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 text-indigo-600" aria-hidden="true" />
                        <span className="ml-3 text-base font-medium text-gray-900">{item.name}</span>
                      </a>
                    ))}
                  </nav>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="py-6 px-5 space-y-6">
                
                <div>
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="w-full flex items-center justify-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-base font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700"
                  >
                    Sign up
                  </a>
                  <p className="mt-6 text-center text-base font-medium text-gray-500">
                    Existing customer?
                    <a href="#" className="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500">
                      Sign in
                    </a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Popover.Panel>
        </Transition>
      </Popover>

      
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: I guess you're using some client-side variables like `window` and `document` in `NavBar`. By the way, without your NavBar's code, it's hard to see through your problems, please share that component implementation too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you show us the `Navbar` code as well? can't really say what's going wrong without taking a look at the code.

Edit:
The problem is, when you import the Navbar component you are using a named import (an import with curly braces), and your Navbar component
is a default export, so you should use a default import like so:

```
import Navbar from "../components/schema/Navbar"
```

notice there are no curly braces.

check out this blog post -https://vhudyma-blog.eu/2020-09-27-default-vs-named-export-what-is-the-difference/

Comment: i've added the navbar component could you take a look at it now

Comment: Could you please explain further what the error is? Maybe show a screenshot?

Comment: uncaught render element?

Comment: @riskylast checkout my edit above

Answer (score 0):

I was importing the function Navbar in a wrong manner. I was destructuring Navbar during import where as it should be a normal import